# Is $y(n) = x(nT)$ causal,time invariant and linear?

Tags: nonlinear-system, signal-processing, invariance, causality

If $T>0$ is the sampling period of a device which produces one output signal $Yn$ from a continuous input signal $x(t)$, and n is any integer, would it be causal,time invariant and/or linear?

My guess would be all three as:

Causality: only depends on current n

Time invariant: a time offset of t yields the same output

$y(n-t) = x((n-t)T)$

Linear as:

$y_{n1} = x_1(nT)$,
$y_{n2} = x_2(nT)$ and

$yn = [x_1(nT)+x_2(nT)] = y_{n1} + y_{n2}$

However I'm not too sure about linearity as it is not specified if the sampling rate actually changes. Any thoughts?

Comment: There is a TON of context missing that prevents a definitive answer from being given. Are the input and output both discrete time signals? One of them? And if they are discrete time, what happens to the points in between the T fold up sample? Just a few of the several questions that should be answered. As detailed of a context of your situation as possible should be edited into your post.

Comment: @NinadMunshi updated with as much possible context

Comment: If $x(t)$ is causal, then $y_n$ is also causal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof of time invariance is incorrect.

Take $x'(t) = x(t-\tau)$. Then

$$y'(n) = x'(nT) = x(nT-\tau) \neq y(n-\tau)$$

There is no such thing as a time invariant transformation from continuous to discrete time.

Comment: And while we're on the subject, your proof of linearity is nonsensical. The transformation is indeed linear, but you need to add the signals, not their domains.

Comment: would it be correct now?